# How to classify a large collection of user entered company names?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, solr, machine-learning, classification

Our site allows users to enter the company they work for as a free form text entry.
Historically we gathered around a few millions of unique entries. Since we put no constraints we ended up with a lot of variations, typos (e.g. over 1000 distinct entries just for McDonald's)

We realized we could provide our users with a great feature if only we could tie these variations together. We compiled a clean list of companies as a starting point using various online sources [Dictionary]

Now, we're trying to find out a best way to deal with the user data source. We thought about assigning some similarity score:
- comparing each entry with [Dictionary], calculating a lexical distance (possibly in Hadoop job)
- taking advantage of some search database (e.g. Solr)

And associate the user enter text this way.

What we're wondering is did anyone go through similar "classification" exercise and could share any tips?

Thanks,
Piotr

Comment: This is offtopic for SO, but you can look for record linkage literature in your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJungblut will check it out. Can you think of any other forum where this question would be relevant and likely to get answered?

Comment: I haven't read it, but based on reviews the recent Jolt Award book "Taming Text" might be worth a read for ideas about fuzzy text matching - http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/

Comment: Why not use clustering algorithm for your data using lexical distance.

Comment: This is what I call the Guns N Roses problem. Google at one time showed the surprising number of different ways people searched for Britney Spears. Lexical distance helps, as do phonetic algorithms like Soundex and Metaphone. We found our best success with a combination of algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use simple **Levenshtein distance** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

A few millions entries - you should be able to process it easily on one computer (no hadoop, or other heavy-weight tools).

Comment: Levenshtein distance is a good place to start, but alone it's not enough to do a good job. Think, for example, of the apparently common misspelling "edicit" for "etiquette." L. distance isn't a lot of help with things like that.

Comment: yes, I agree, there is still no artificial intelligence equal to humans - every technique has some disadvantages... As you wrote: it is a good place to start.